# Double Squares (Facebook Hacker Cup 2011) in Java

Tags: java, algorithm

**So it works fine, two major changes that were needed is only checking up to the square root of x (required also flipping my check case from checkign for remainder to checking exponentiation). The other change is that using a double was obviously reckless as the numbers will go way above the maximum double.**

This is a challenge from CodeEval, I suppose first asked by Facebook. This is what my brain spit out immediately. It passes all hand driven test cases (e.g. 10-> 1, 25->2, 3-> 0). I haven't seen any other solutions because I want to see how I did with my own thoughts first. If I'm way off base and this will never work, I'd appreciate someone just saying so :P. If this will never work and I have to figure out a new way, I'll spend more time dwelling on this one.

I don't immediately see any case it won't satisfy..but that's not the issue. I was never very good at calculating run time complexity, but I think I've got way too much nesting going on.

I thought by checking from the right and left (This is a little more clear in the code), I would seriously decrease the run time. I'm not sure if that's just not doing is as effectively as I thought, or the other loops are still too much...or both.

Any thoughts? Is this salvageable or should I scrap it and think about it in a new way?

Question and code follow. Thanks for looking :-)

> Credits: This challenge appeared in the Facebook Hacker Cup 2011.
>   A double-square number is an integer X which can be expressed as the sum of two perfect squares. For example, 10 is a double-square because 10 = 3^2 + 1^2. Your task in this problem is, given X, determine the number of ways in which it can be written as the sum of two squares. For example, 10 can only be written as 3^2 + 1^2 (we don't count 1^2 + 3^2 as being different). On the other hand, 25 can be written as 5^2 + 0^2 or as 4^2 + 3^2.
>   NOTE: Do NOT attempt a brute force approach. It will not work. The following constraints hold:
>   0 <= X <= 2147483647
>   1 <= N <= 100

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class DoubleSquares {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File file = new File(args[0]);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
        String line;
        while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
            int total = 0;
            String[] lineArray = line.split("\\s");
            if (lineArray.length > 0) {
                double x = (double) Integer.parseInt(lineArray[0]);
                if (x == 0){total++;} //special case if input is 0
                double sLeft = 0.00;  //left boundary to indicate where to stop (so we dont repeat e.g. 4+1 and 1+4)
                for(double sRight = x; sRight > sLeft; sRight--){
                    if (Math.sqrt(sRight) % 1 == 0){//has no remainder then it's a candidate..
                        double needed = x-sRight;
                        if (Math.sqrt(needed) % 1 == 0){//check of solution to what makes sRight == x is a perfect square.
                            total++; //increment if so.
                        }
                        sLeft = needed;
                    }
                }
            }
            System.out.println(total);
        }
    }
}
```

To be a little more clear, this seems to work just fine, but when I submit to the CodeEval auto grader, it terminates after 10 seconds of running. Too slow or stuck with some large input no doubt.

Comment: You're also checking the squares of x-1, x-2, ... what for? Also the sqrt and modulu are quite heavy functions, you could use a simple multiplication instead

Comment: `"1 <= N <= 100"` - What's `N`? And can you give a high-level explanation of your code?

Comment: @Dukeling N is the quantity of numbers to be processed

Comment: Your algorithm is brute force, so it won't make it. AFAICS you should start from the square root of the number and go down to zero or to any other number that can make it.

Comment: I see, my idea was there in heart but I didn't implement it. I indeed meant to check starting with the sRight boundary as the square root of x.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This problem was discussed by Edsgar Dijkstra in his 1976 book *The Discipline of Programming*. Dijkstra finds all pairs in a single pass as *x* sweeps downward from the integer square root of *n* and *y* sweeps upward from zero. Consider the function `B(x, y)` that returns all suitable pairs between *x* and *y*, guided by the following three recursive rules plus a recursive base:

- If x² + y² < n, then B(x, y) = B(x, y+1), because there is no possible solution (u, v) with x ≥ u, since that would imply u² + v² < n.
- If x² + y² = n, then the pair (x, y) is a solution, B(x, y) = (x, y) ⋃ B(x-1, y+1), and the sweep continues.
- If x² + y² > n, then B(x, y) = B(x-1, y), because there is no possible solution with any x.
- Finally, if x < y, B(x, y) is the null set, and recursion stops.

Here's how I wrote the solution in Scheme at [my blog](http://programmingpraxis.com/2010/01/05/the-sum-of-two-squares/); I'll leave it to you to translate to Java:

```
(define (squares n)
  (let loop ((x (isqrt n)) (y 0) (zs '()))
    (cond ((< x y) zs)
          ((< (+ (* x x) (* y y)) n) (loop x (+ y 1) zs))
          ((< n (+ (* x x) (* y y))) (loop (- x 1) y zs))
          (else (loop (- x 1) (+ y 1) (cons (list x y) zs))))))
```

And here are some examples, which you may find useful as test cases:

```
> (squares 50)
((5 5) (7 1))
> (squares 48612265)
((5008 4851) (5139 4712) (5179 4668) (5243 4596) (5432 4371)
 (5613 4136) (5656 4077) (5691 4028) (5832 3821) (5907 3704)
 (6048 3469) (6124 3333) (6213 3164) (6259 3072) (6384 2803)
 (6404 2757) (6413 2736) (6556 2373) (6576 2317) (6637 2136)
 (6651 2092) (6756 1723) (6772 1659) (6789 1588) (6853 1284)
 (6899 1008) (6917 876) (6944 627) (6948 581) (6952 531)
 (6971 132) (6972 59))
> (squares 999)
()
```

Comment: Thank you! It always comes back to Dijkstra :d "Dijkstra finds all pairs in a single pass as x sweeps downward from the integer square root of n and y sweeps upward from zero"

This is exactly what I was hoping to implement, albeit, much more elegant than my notepad scratching. I just forgot the crucial step of starting from the square root (though I have it written in my pseudo code >.<). I think I missed one case, though. I'll give your blog a look tonight! Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

My idea:

- Generate all squares between 0 and 2147483647
- For each X:

  - count = 0
  - Have 2 iterators - one starting from the left and one starting from the right
  - If `left + right = X`, increase the count, increase the left iterator and decrease the right one
  - If `left + right > X`, decrease the right one
  - If `left + right < X`, increase the left one
  - Stop when `left` bypasses `right`

As an optimization, we don't need to start all the way on the right, we can instead do a binary search for the starting position.

Test code:

```
private static int binarySearch(long[] a, long key)
{
    int low = 0;
    int high = a.length - 1;

    while (low <= high) {
        int mid = (low + high) >>> 1;
        long midVal = a[mid];

        if (midVal < key)
            low = mid + 1;
        else if (midVal > key)
            high = mid - 1;
        else
            return mid;
    }
    return Math.min(low, a.length-1);
}

public static void main(String[] args)
{
  long[] squares = new long[46341]; // ceil(sqrt(2147483647)) = 46341
  long val = 0;
  int pos = 0;
  while (true)
  {
     long square = val*val;
     // sanity check, can also use pos >= squares.length
     if (square > 2147483647l)
        break;
     squares[pos++] = square;
     val++;
  }
  int X = 10;
  int left = 0;
  int right = binarySearch(squares, X);
  int count = 0;
  for (; left <= right; )
  {
     //Collections.b
     long l = squares[left] + squares[right];
     if (l == X)
     {
        count++;
        left++;
        right--;
     }
     else if (l > X)
     {
        right--;
     }
     else
     {
        left++;
     }
  }
  System.out.println(count);
}
```

Comment: Why not just generate all squares up to the given N? For example if it's 10, then you only need to generate 1^2, 2^2, 3^2 because 4^2 is greater than 10.

Comment: @ShashankGupta Because you're probably given many X's, so you only need to generate these squares once, and you can then reuse them for each X.

Comment: An alternative to “Generate all squares between 0 and 2147483647” is “Read target values into array D; compute Dmax = {max value in D}; generate all squares between 0 and Dmax”.  But the scope for time savings is minimal because it probably only takes a half millisecond to generate the 46340 squares below 2^31.

Comment: @jwpat7 ... and they typically include at least one test case very close to the upper limit.

Comment: I just realized that you can look up the square root of the number rather than doing a binary search - `int right = (int)Math.round(Math.sqrt(X));`. I'm not sure which would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

My idea is :

- Find the greatest a or b we can have : `int x1 = int(Math.sqrt(x))`
- List all the squares from 0 to x1 in an array `long[] squares = new long[50000];`
- now this loop :

int right = binarySearch(squares, math.sqrt(x1));

```
int count = 0;

for(int i = 0 ; i < right; i++){

   if(Math.sqrt(x-squares[i]) == int(Math.sqrt(x-squares[i]))){

      count++;

   } else if(int(Math.sqrt(x-squares[i])) < squares[i]) {

      break;

   }

}

System.out.println(x);
```

so each time we check if the difference between the element from the squares array and X is a perfect square,

Now this is just my idea, so please, when you'll comment, do it kindly !!